# Динамическое добавление блока

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

у меня есть небольшая форма которая представляет из себя чек, в которой в селекте выбирается товар и рядом в инпуте количество этого товара.
В чеке естественно может быть больше одного товара.

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать добавление новых полей для выбора товара.

```
<div class="sales">
            <div class="sale flex-container">
                 <div class="name">
                     <select size="1" name="product[]"><br>
                         <?php
                            $product = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM product");
                            while ($prod = mysqli_fetch_assoc($product)){
                         ?>
                                <option value="<? echo $prod['id_product']; ?>"><? echo $prod['product_name']; ?></option>
                         <?}?>
                     </select>
                 </div>
                 <div class="quantity"><input type="number"></div>
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="+">
        </div>
```

Повторно добавлять нужно все что внутри блока с классом sale, и оставлять кнопку для добавления.

Comment: Что за поля хотите добавить? Эти данные все в таблице `product` лежат?

Comment: @InDevX, я хочу повторять блок  с классом sale  и все что в нем. Например мне нужно добавить 5 товаров, значит нужно вставить этот блок еще 4 раза

Comment: При нажатии на `+`, так?

Comment: @InDevX, да, одно нажатие "+", один новый блок.

Comment: вот рабочий [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/kXmpY/1/)

Comment: @InDevX, очень помогли, спасибо!